# Is it possible to register more than one CXF interceptors at the same phase?

Tags: cxf, interceptor

I want to have different class being registered for different purpose to be invoked at the same phase(Phase.PRE_INVOKE). Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html.

> InterceptorChains are divided up into Phases. The phase that each
>   interceptor runs in is declared in the interceptor's constructor. Each
>   phase may contain many interceptors. On the incoming chains, you'll
>   have the following phases:...

So short answer: yes